# Change wording of "Excerpt/Wiki not helpful"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

Oh look, someone made a bunch of tag wiki excerpts/wikis that don't follow guidelines. I'll just click this Wiki Not Helpful reason when rejecting them:

[image]

And the next one:

[image]

Wait what the f- the order changed! When you're used to the position of the rejection reason, it's very jarring to see what's essentially the same reject reason in a different place (reordering most of the other entries too)

Please retitle the "Excerpt/wiki not helpful" message so that both use the same start. This will help users scan for the right reason regardless of excerpt/wiki and keeps them in alphabetical order.

I personally recommend:

> unhelpful tag wiki/excerpt

Which keeps it in alphabetical order but keeps it clear which option you're picking at a glance, which avoids this jumbled order business.

Comment: For a minute there, I thought you were showing me two different dialogs, but now I realize that this is a *permanent* change. You can't just get accustomed to the new location?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you misunderstood. One of those is the Excerpt reject dialog, one is the Wiki reject dialog. Both are live and both differ just enough to be confusing (for no real reason, it's just due to the name + auto-alpha sort)

Comment: I would simply change both dialogs to **Not Helpful.**

Comment: That works for me too; made my suggestion just to keep the meaning as similar as possible, but there's not much reason to include tag wiki/excerpt in there. Unhelpful is unhelpful

Comment: Weird, I was [grumbling about this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1039161#1039161) just five minutes before you posted.